# Проблема с NavigationView

Tags: android

Есть MainActyvity с

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
               android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
                app:defaultNavHost="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

@menu/drawer_view

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="First" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="Second" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="Third" />
</group>
```

Ошибка такая:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp/com.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас используются разные библиотеки `com.android.support:appcompat` и `com.android.support:design`. Необходимо установить одинаковые версии.

Comment: ошибка сменилась на:The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.

Comment: https://github.com/invweb/Alex_test_app смотреть тут

Comment: У вас в разметке toolbar.xml используется виджет из android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar замените его. Касаемо ошибки попробуйте это https://medium.com/@begalesagar/migrate-an-existing-project-to-androidx-from-support-libraries-adbac897089b